# Docker containers takes too much time to process tasks

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, containers, azure-virtual-machine

I am using 3 containers as microservices and RabbitMQ for communication b/w them. I am using azure VMs for running the container. The machine has **64 GB ram and 32 cores**. The architecture is given below
[image]

Container C1: A python web server just to receive request and small db operation
Container C2: Processing but not intensive
Container C3: Processing High Intensive tasks

When i try to process one web request it takes around 20 mins including all container (C3 takes around 90% of that). Then I tested with high cores machine (eg., **64 core, 128 GB RAM and 72 cores and 144 GB RAM**) I was shocked to see that time also increases but I guess it should be less because there are large cpu cores.

Using htop I can see that **C3** container uses all cores 100%. When i tried with multiple web requests (=10) time took to complete processing for one request is around 40-50 mins becuase they all are handled in parallel in C2 & C3. I dont see the use of large number of cpu cores in docker containers.
Is there is any thing wrong with the architecture or should i start new containers for ever web request (C2 & C3).

Comment: I am guessing you are using Kubernetes to orchestrate the containers since you have tagged the question with k8s, considering that, in the k8s master see whether there is any CPU core lock using (kubectl get limitrange). Refer to [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/). Maybe it's showing 100% percent utilization of granted CPU to the cluster.

Comment: My apologies I am not using kubernetes now but will use. Right now I am testing it on local by manually running these 3 containers.

Comment: Instead of running the jobs in parallel inside the container, I would suggest you spin up a container every time you get the job, try to achieve minimum overhead for a container. Let's get the CPU telemetry once you achieve that, let me know.

Comment: Ok. Just to add extra point, I tried invoking containers using python script (now webserver is not docker container) in separate thread for each web request and surprisingly it is much faster as compared to previous scenario. In this case nothing is changed except the architecture. But the only thing is that there is new container for every request. But it's on the same VM.

Comment: That was probably the reason, because the previous architecture there was no point of having containers since you are not scaling them, now that you are doing that, and every container is handling it's individual requests, I believe that's what has sped up the execution time. Kudos!